# Displaying images stored in Openshift server

Tags: unix, openshift

I want to display image stored in Openshift server using img tag. Now, I have created a folder in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR in the server. After going into the directory, I pwd to get the complete path :

```
    /var/lib/openshift/52002234335h7b0000163/app-root/data/pamphlets
```

So, I specified the path in img tag as

```
        <img src="/var/lib/openshift/52002234335h7b0000163/approot/data/pamphlets/1.png" class="map" alt="Image Not Available"
```

I even tried out

```
      file:///var/lib/openshift/52002234335h7b0000163/app-root/data/pamphlets/1.png
```

but nothing is working. Can anyone point me out what is the mistake I am making?

Comment: Have you already fixed it? because u have got similar problem!!! help pls!!!

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are developing a web application. In that case you are missing the fact that you should use the path defined on the web server's DocumentRoot. Then you should use that as the root for your web-accessible files. So, for instance /pamphlets/ will be the path if your webserver's documentRoot points to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. If you are using one of the preloaded cartridges make sure that happens first.

Comment: Thank you for the reply....I am trying to find the document root of my openshift server but not able to find the suitable command...can you please tell me how to find that or change that?

Comment: Can you tell me more about your application configuration, for instance which cartridges are you using?

Comment: I create app using command rhc app create -a appName -t jbossews-1.0, then I add mysql cartridge in it.

Comment: Right. Then you should be able to use `<img src="/pamphlets/image.png">` for HTTP publishing

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
<img src="/var/lib/openshift/52002234335h7b0000163/approot/data/pamphlets/1.png" class="map" alt="Image Not Available" />
```

To:

```
<img src="/pamphlets/1.png" class="map" alt="Image Not Available" />
```

You don't need $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR => /var/lib/openshift/52002234335h7b0000163/approot/data/

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jboss before but the basic method is saving your files in your project folder and then symlink to the Openshift data directory.